# Start Index of table at 0 in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I want to set the index of table-members, but still name them. Is that possible?

```
local table = {
    ["cat"] = {
        ["fish"] = { stuff = "bla1", stuff2 = "bla" },
        ["mouse"] = { stuff = "bla2", stuff2 = "bla" },
        ["bird"] = { stuff = "bla3", stuff2 = "bla" },
    },
    ["dog"] = {
        ["fish"] = { stuff = "bla1", stuff2 = "bla" },
        ["mouse"] = { stuff = "bla2", stuff2 = "bla" },
        ["bird"] = { stuff = "bla3", stuff2 = "bla" },
    },
}
```

`table["cat"][1]` is `fish`, but I want that `table["cat"][0]` is `fish`, how can I achieve that?

**Edit:**
I still want to be able to access `fish` with `table["cat"]["fish"]`.

**Edit2:**

What when I try to do it viceversa? http://repl.it/MCu
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `table["cat"][1]` is `nil`. All your tables are hash-like, none are array-like.

Comment: Oh : O So how can I make them array-like?

Comment: There is a standard module named `table`. It would be a good idea to not name a variable `table` to avoid confusion, unless the goal really is to localize the global. The same is true of the other standard modules `coroutine`, `string`, `math`, `io`, `os`, and `debug`. Overloading any of those names is likely a recipe for confusion.

Comment: Yes, just used it for the example ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to clarify `table["cat"][1]` *is not* a `fish` -- your table example above does not make use of the index part of the table at all. To use the index part of the table, the key itself has to be an integer.

Modifying your example above:

```
local animal = {
    cat = {
        fish = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
        mouse = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
        bird = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
    },
    dog = {
        fish = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
        mouse = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
        bird = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
    },
}
```

If you want `animal.cat.fish` and `animal.cat[1]` to have the same value (the same lua table) just do a regular assignment:

```
animal.cat[1] = animal.cat.fish
-- and likewise if you want index 0:
animal.cat[0] = animal.cat.fish
```

Note that many of the standard lua functions that work with tables start counting from 1.

Comment: Is there a difference beetween `local animal = {` and `local ["animal"] = {`?

Comment: @Fox the second one isn't syntactically valid lua.

Comment: Hmm, but it works? I know someone coding that way, why is he doing that? : O

Comment: @Fox +1. This solution looks clearer than mine, consider using it. Just remember use both keys to reference the same table, not using two tables with same content.

Comment: @Fox You are mistaken. You can test this out in http://repl.it/. It will actually give you a syntax error when you try to compile that chunk. Perhaps you remembered it wrong?

Comment: @Fox you need to put `_LEG`, `_ARM` and `_HEAD` in square brackets or it's going to be interpreted as a string key. eg. `cat = { [_LEG] = {name = "leg1"} } -- etc..`.

Answer (score 4):

Your tables and the tables nested inside tables are pure hash-style, none array-style.

The array-style Lua tables:

```
local t = {"cat", "dog", "fish"}
```

is just a syntactic sugar of the equivalent form:

```
local t = {[1] = "cat", [2] = "dog", [3] = "fish"}
```

You can use all types of keys except `nil`, sure you can use integer keys starting from `0`:

```
local t = {[0] = "cat", [1] = "dog", [2] = "fish"}
```

Note that starting from `0` made `t` no longer a sequence, so you lost the power of the table functions that is used only on sequences, like the `#`operator, `ipairs`, etc.

---

To build a table with different keys, you can make the value table first, and then bind different keys to the same table like this:

```
local v = {
    ["fish"] = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
    ["mouse"] = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
    ["bird"] = { stuff = "bla", stuff2 = "bla" },
}

local t = {
    ["cat"] = v,
    [0] = v,
}
print(t.cat.fish.stuff, t[0].fish.stuff)
-- Output: bla     bla
```

In this way, `t.cat` and `t[0]` access the same table.

Note that you can use the syntax sugar form `table.cat.fish` instead of `table["cat"]["fish"]`

Comment: Okay, but how can I make that "cat" is a table too? I want to call it like table.cat.stuff, but table[0].stuff too. Are that two keys then?

Comment: @Fox You can make another table, then build the table with both keys `"cat"` and `0` using that table as value. But that's a little messy to deal with, are you sure you really need this?

Comment: Yeah, I need it. But how can I build the table with both keys?

Comment: The correct syntax is `{[1] = "cat", [2] = "dog", [3] = "fish"}`.